# fatal: protocol ''https' is not supported in Git

Tags: git, azure, github

I tried to push the repo to my `azure` remote by runnng `git push azure master`. The remote URL is `'https://<myid>@ndas.scm.azurewebsites.net/<myapp>.git'`.

The problem is, it says protocol 'https' is not supported

Please see the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: that @ looks really funky to me.

Comment: i'm serious. https://imagebin.ca/v/4KRYxoV8W0BU

Comment: @PoomaniGP, the `@` looked weird because your user name wasn't showing up.  It was inside angle brackets (like HTML tags are) so it wasn't rendered. Your repo name wasn't visible either. I've edited your question so it looks less strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is, it says protocol 'https' is not supported

It actually *doesn't* say that. Here's what it actually says:

> fatal: protocol ''https' is not supported

Note the two single quotes at the beginning and one at the end. The first and last are quoting the protocol for the error message, but the second quote is *part of* the protocol being rejected: `'https`.

Note also the full output you see from `git remote -v`. Your `azure` remote URLs include literal leading and trailing single quotes while your `origin` remote URLs (which are presumably working) don't.

Try running

```
git remote set-url azure https://poomani98@ndas.scm.azurewebsites.net/ndas.git
```

to set the remote URL to `https://poomani98@ndas.scm.azurewebsites.net/ndas.git` instead of `'https://poomani98@ndas.scm.azurewebsites.net/ndas.git'`, then pushing again.